# Tensorflow TFDV does not work with images

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-data-validation

I'm trying to get TFDV working with RGB images as feature inputs, reading from a TFRecords file. I can read/write the image data to TFRecord files fine. Here's the relevant code snippets for writing, where img is a numpy [32,32,3] array:

```
feature = {'train/label': _int64_feature(y_train[i]),
           'train/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring()))
          }
```

And reading back:

```
read_features = {'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
             'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}
```

I can then use frombuffer and reshape to get back my image correcty.

The issue is that when I run tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord() using that TFRecords file. It throws an error :

```
ValueError: '\xff ...... \x87' has type str, but isn't valid UTF-8 encoding. Non-UTF-8 strings must be converted to unicode objects before being added. [while running 'GenerateStatistics/RunStatsGenerators/TopKStatsGenerator/TopK_ConvertToSingleFeatureStats']
```

I've tried all kinds of different ways of writing the images using astype(unicode) and more, but I can;t get this working.

Any ideas please?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started#computing_descriptive_data_statistics) the records should be in the TF example format. So, can you please use example gen to convert it into tf examples and then feed these tf examples to tfdv. This should solve your issue. Please try this and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
image_string = open(image_location, 'rb').read()
feature = {'train/label': _int64_feature(y_train[i]),
           'train/image': _bytes_feature(image_string)
          }
```

referred from [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#walkthrough_reading_and_writing_image_data)